# Django Q filter, cant get results in a single query

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-filter, django-q

I want to make a query with multiple conditions to get some objects out of my Order model, but i can't find a way to get all the results in a single query. Besides the option to make 2 queries, i would like to know if this is possible with just one so i can create a CSV sheet with all of these orders(this part already works so i will stick to the query).
The conditions:

paymethod: Paypal and Mollie
created_at: in hours 15:00 and 16:00

&

paymethod: ApplePay
created_at: in hours 17:00 and 18:00

The two queries:

```
Order.objects.all() \
.filter(Q(paymethod="Paypal") | 
        Q(paymethod="Mollie") & 
        Q(created_at__hour__in=(15, 16)))


Order.objects.all() \
.filter(Q(paymethod="ApplePay") 
        Q(created_at__hour__in=(17, 18)))
```

These two queries work fine seperatly, but i would like to know if it is possible to combine them to a single query.

i have tried something like:

```
Order.objects.all() \
.filter(Q(paymethod="Paypal" | "Mollie", created_at__hour__in=(15, 16)) \
& Q(paymethod="ApplePay", created_at__hour__in=(17, 18)))
```

The above does not work because of: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'.
So instead of `paymethod="Paypal" | "Mollie"` i tried: `paymethod="Paypal" | paymethod="Mollie"`
But unfortunately that doesn't work too..

Would really appreciate if someone can point me into the right direction. I'm still learning django and django Q is new for me. If any additional information is needed please let me know! thanks!

Comment: You are already on the correct track with the first query you show. Why don't you simply use `|` and `&` on the Q objects like you do in the first query? If it's an issue of operator precedence try using brackets.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I knew i was close on the first query but i couldnt firgure it out. (probably because the lack of sleep..) but its working now thanks to the answers below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to use `Q` at all. This use case should be covered by `QuerySet.filter` and `Queryset.union`.

```
Order.objects.filter(
    paymethod__in=["Paypal", "Mollie"], 
    created_at__hour__in=[15, 16],
).union(
    Order.objects.filter(
        paymethod="ApplePay", 
        created_at__hour__in=[17, 18],
    )
)
```

When you pass multiple arguments to `filter`, django will use sql `AND` in the resulting sql statement. This is equivalent to joining your `Q` objects with the set intersection operator `&`.

The QuerySet.union method is equivalent to the `|` operator on querysets
and will translate to sql `UNION`. (The `|` operator on Q objects will translate to sql `OR` operations.)

Django's queryset methods that accept `param__in=[...]` will translate those arguments to sql IN statements. This should be equivalent to (give the same result as) using `Q | Q`.

```
filter(paymethod__in=["Paypal", "Mollie"])
# produces same results as 
filter(Q(paymethod="Paypal") | Q(paymethod="Mollie"))
```

I suspect IN is faster in typical cases, but you would have benchmark to confirm this.

Comment: `union` does not use SQL `OR`, it actually uses the SQL `UNION` operator.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: You're right. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Thank you very much sir! i got it working now with the `Queryset.union` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using nested Q object as below:

```py
Order.objects.filter(
    Q(
        Q(paymethod="Paypal") | Q(paymethod="Mollie") & Q(created_at__hour__in=(15, 16))
    ) |
    Q(
        Q(paymethod="ApplePay") & Q(created_at__hour__in=(17, 18))
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can nest your subqueries even further, like this:

```py
Order.objects.filter(
    Q(
        Q(paymethod="Paypal") | 
        Q(paymethod="Mollie") & 
        Q(created_at__hour__in=(15, 16))
    ) |
    Q(
        Q(paymethod="ApplePay") 
        Q(created_at__hour__in=(17, 18))
    )
)
```

UPD:
Also, if you don't want to use 'Q' object for some reason, you can "merge" the querysets:

```py
q1 = Order.objects.all() \
.filter(Q(paymethod="Paypal") | 
        Q(paymethod="Mollie") & 
        Q(created_at__hour__in=(15, 16)))

q2 = Order.objects.all() \
.filter(Q(paymethod="ApplePay") 
        Q(created_at__hour__in=(17, 18)))

result = q1 | q2
```